# node.js zlib on AWS Lambda result doesn't match local environment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, zlib

I'm trying to get AWS Lambda function to fetch gzipped log file from S3, unzip it (gunzip), parse and push it to ElasticSearch. I'm stuck on unzipping part. When I run below function locally, it fetches the file from S3 and I get expected results:

`Buffer size before unzipping 72535
Buffer size after unzipping 444365`

However when I run the same code on AWS Lambda, I get only partial result back:

`Buffer size before unzipping 72535
Buffer size after unzipping 567`

```
function s3ToES(bucket, key, context) {
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }, next);
        },
        function unzip(data, next) {
            console.log("Buffer size before unzipping", data.Body.byteLength);
            var plainText = zlib.gunzipSync(data.Body);
            console.log("Buffer size after unzipping", plainText.byteLength);
        }
    ], function(error) {
        if (error) {
            context.fail(error);
        } else {
            context.done();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: @DaniloSalvio no, I decided to skip Lambda altogether for my project.